# How to download the logo for a given space on Confluence

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

There is no way to download the logo for a given space? I clicked on the space and "Look and Feel" but I couldn't find a way to download the logo.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mouna,the re is no UI menu foor this, but it is possible to download the logo by:

1. Get the direct link to a pace icon by REST API ({wiki}/rest/api/space/{KEY}). e.g. "/download/attachments/443127157/TBB?version=1&modificationDate=1685552917000&api=v2"
2. Take logos from the Confluence Data folders (logos, user images, etc. are stored in Attachments folders)